# Commit images to a github repository using a browser

Tags: git, github, github-api

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865752/upload-images-to-github-from-the-browser) is probably asking the same thing, but it's not clear and I don't want to change the intent of his question. So I'll ask a new one and make it clear my intent.

I have a repository that includes image assets for an iPhone app.

I'd like the designers at my company to be able to commit new images into the repository. But I don't want them to have to use command line git or SourceTree or similar.

GitHub.com allows you to edit text files through the browser and commit those changes to the repository. Is there any way to do the same thing through the GitHub website, but for non-text files (e.g. Images.)

If there isn't a way to do it that's officially supported by GitHub, is there any third party site that makes this possible through the GitHub API?

Comment: Github how has the ability to upload files.  https://github.com/<org>/<repo>/upload

Answer (score 0):

I don't think github supports such functionality on its web app. If it does, who's to stop it from becoming an image hosting platform. Heck, with its social elements and power of git, it will beat the hell out of flickr and instagram.

But no.

Comment: I was going to post the same answer to the other question. But I was hoping someone else would prove me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could have them add image URLs (of external images hosted on e.g. cloud file storage) to e.g. a json file.

If you have security issues regarding images changing after merge, you could run image checksum validation in testing or on deploy (http://www.controlledvocabulary.com/imagedatabases/de-dupe.html).