# How do I add new files to a shared github repo?

Tags: git, github, upload, git-commit

I have a team project and we are using github to shared any files. I need to add a png image into the repo's images folder. How do I do it through the website?

Comment: It didn't really help. I clicked on the "create new file here" plus button on github website for the appropriate folder but it just gives me a text editor. How am I supposed to add the image exactly? Why isn't it as simple as a file upload?

Comment: It seems that GitHub indeed only allows you to add a text file on the website; I can't really blame them, since Git is meant for such files (not binary files such as images). However, you can always commit the image to your local repo and then push to GitHub.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865752/upload-images-to-github-from-the-browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. I downloaded the Github application. Added the repo by clicking clone to desktop. Once added into the application, right clicked on the repo and selected open in finder. This opened the entire github repo content. I selected the right folder and drag and dropped the file. Back in the application, I had to click on commit changes.

Comment: Cool, but this approach uses the GitHub app, not just the GitHub website `:)`